# Understanding from where a recurrence of polynomials comes from

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, radicals, interpolation

In chapter $7$ of Principles of Mathematical Analysis ($3$rd edition) by Walter Rudin, the exercise $23$ says:

> Put $P_0=0$, and define, for $n=0,1,2,\dots,$
>   $$P_{n+1}(x)=P_{n}(x)+\frac{x^2-P_{n}^2(x)}{2}.$$
>   Prove that
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}P_{n}(x)=|x|,$$
>   uniformly on $[-1,1]$.

I am interested here in the origin of the polynomials (i.e. how Rudin came up with them) rather than a solution to the exercise.  My intuition is that the polynomials come as some sort of approximation of $\sqrt{x^2}$, but I am unsure how to use an approximation of the square root function to derive the recurrence $P_0(x) = 0$ and $$P_{n+1}(x) = P_n(x) + \frac {x^2 - P_n^2(x)} 2$$ as an approximation of $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: Not everyone has a copy of Baby Rudin at hand, so please include the crucial details with an [edit] to keep your post self-contained.

Comment: And there are also presumably multiple versions of Baby Rudin. My copy, 3rd ed., only has 19 exercises in chapter 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of merely labouring the obvious:

Imagine that we wanted a method for approximating $\sqrt{a}$ for any $a \geqslant 0$ with an increasing sequence $(b_n)_{n \geqslant 0}$ whose limit is $\sqrt{a}$ and which is defined by
$$
b_0 = 0, \ \, b_{n+1} = f(b_n) \ \, (n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots)
$$
for some "simple" function $f$ defined on $[0, \sqrt{a}].$

About the "simplest" function we might think of that might work is
$$
f(x) = x + \frac{a - x^2}{2}.
$$

In order to suit our purpose, however, $f$ must satisfy the condition $f(x) \leqslant \sqrt{a}$ for all $x \in [0, \sqrt{a}].$

Adapting the hint given in Rudin's question, we have
$$
\sqrt{a} - f(x) = (\sqrt{a} - x)\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{a} + x}{2}\right)
$$
so $f$ will be usable iff $(\sqrt{a} + x)/2 \leqslant 1$ for all $x \in [0, \sqrt{a}].$ This is equivalent to $\sqrt{a} \leqslant 1,$ that is, to $a \leqslant 1.$

If we're stubborn, we can use our method to approximate $\sqrt{a}$ for all $a \geqslant 0,$ by finding an integer $N$ such that $N^2 \geqslant a,$ and calculating: $$
\sqrt{a} = N\sqrt{\frac{a}{N^2}}.
$$

Thus we can make do, at a pinch, with this crackpot method that only works for $a \in [0, 1].$

Starting with $b_0 = 0,$ it is clear, much as in Rudin's hint, that for all $n$ we have $0 \leqslant b_n \leqslant b_{n+1} \leqslant \sqrt{a}$ and:
$$
\sqrt{a} - b_n \leqslant \sqrt{a}\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}\right)^n.
$$
So, indeed,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = \sqrt{a}.
$$

Convergence is stupidly slow, so it was never a practical scheme for numerical computation. It suits Rudin's theoretical purpose, though, because he can use the inequality
$$
x \left(1 - \frac{x}2\right)^n < \frac2{n+1} \quad (0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1; \ n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots)
$$
(I proved this by differentiating, but perhaps Rudin has a neat trick in mind?) to infer that the convergence of the sequence $(b_n)$ to the limit $\sqrt{a}$ is uniform for all $a \in [0, 1].$

Clearly, $b_n$ is a polynomial in $a$ (of degree $2^{n-1},$ for $n \geqslant 1$).

Writing $a = x^2,$ we thus have a sequence of polynomials in $x$ that converges uniformly to $\left\lvert x \right\rvert$ for $x \in [-1, 1].$

I'll get me coat!

Comment: @Brahadeesh In regard to your edit, which I rejected: I think there may be a difference in usage between the UK (where I am) and the US and some other countries. My UK dictionary (Chambers) gives very different meanings to the transitive verbs "labour" and "belabour". To "labour the obvious" or "labour the point" is a common idiom here. On the other hand, "belabouring" is approximately the treatment that has been handed out to poor old Jeremy Corbyn for the last five years. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the usage to me :) I must admit I have learnt something new today regarding the usage of "labour" vs. "belabour".

Comment: @Brahadeesh I didn't research it thoroughly, but this thread has a ring of truth: [I have no wish to labour the obvious | WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-have-no-wish-to-labour-the-obvious.2043565/).

Comment: It appears my standard Apple dictionary is a little impoverished even when set to "English UK". The online Cambridge dictionary has a nice entry for "[labouring the point](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/labour-the-point)" but none for "belabouring the point", unlike on my laptop.